# How to send from a server through a TCP socket through a specific port

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

I have a server (in C) that gets a message sent by a client and then the server should sends an answer. The client sends the message through a port (e.g. 1345) and should get the answer through a different one (e.g. 2345).

I'm getting the message from the client, but I don't know why I can't get the answer through port 2345.

The server's code is:

```
void *CreateTCPSocket(void *p) {
    
    int srcPort = 1345;
    int dstPort = 2345;
    struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_from;
    struct sockaddr_in sockaddr_to;
    int sockaddr_from_len = sizeof(sockaddr_from);
    int sockaddr_to_len = sizeof(sockaddr_to);
    uint8_t recv_message[MSS];
    bool msg_received = false;


    // Create TCP socket
    int fd_sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    
    if (fd_sock == -1){
        exit(1);
    }

    // Configure src port
    sockaddr_from.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr_from.sin_port = htons(srcPort);
    sockaddr_from.sin_addr = ip_src;

    sockaddr_to.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sockaddr_to.sin_port = htons(destPort);
    sockaddr_to.sin_addr = ip_dst;

    if((ret_bind = bind(fd_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr_from, sizeof(sockaddr_from))) < 0){
        perror("ERROR bind");
        exit(1);
    } 

    while(1){
        if (listen(fd_sock, 100) < 0) {
            perror("listen");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
  
        new_socket = accept(fd_sock, (struct sockaddr*)&sockaddr_from,(socklen_t*)&sockaddr_from_len)

        if (new_socket > 0){
            int res_sock = recvfrom(new_socket, recv_message, MSS, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sockaddr_from, (socklen_t*)&sockaddr_from_len);
            
                msg_received = true;
            
        }

        char* sendMessage = getTCPMessageOut();             
            
        int sent_bytes = strlen(sendMessage);
        int res_sock = -1;

        while (sent_bytes>0) {
            res_sock = sendto(new_socket, sendMessage, sizeof(sendMessage), MSG_NOSIGNAL, (struct sockaddr *)&cfg->sockaddr_to, (socklen_t)sizeof(cfg->sockaddr_to));
            if (res_sock > -1){
                break;
            }
            sent_bytes-=res_sock;
        }
        
        if (res_sock == -1){
            perror("Send Error");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works if I use the same port for both client and server. The issue is only send the message through the different port.

Comment: The server doesn't send the reply to a specific port. It accepts the connection, and then just sends replies on that socket.

Comment: `sendto` and `recvfrom` are used with UDP sockets, not TCP.

Comment: I suppose your client needs to make two connections, then. One on 1234 and one on 2345. And the server must be able to tell that they go together.